# Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] laravel 8

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I install Redis cach driver in laravel 8 project. After refresh I am getting this error  Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]. I cant find out my problem. where is the problem. anyone can tell me.

i used this commend by the

```
composer require predis/predis

.env file : CACHE_DRIVER=redis

I used this command in the controller :

public function homeproductdisplay () {
     $data= Cache()->remember('Product', 60, function() { 
     return DB::table('Product')   
       ->select(array('Product_name','status','slug','regular_price','gallery_image'))
       ->where('status', '=', 'Instock')
       ->limit(30)
       ->get();
 });
```

Comment: Do you have redis server running in localhost?

Comment: have you installed Redis in your system ?

Comment: @DanielMesa yes I was install in my localhost.

Comment: @BhargavRangani Yes I was install in my local system using this commend "composer require predis/predis"

Comment: Type `redis-cli` in your command line

Comment: @mikebension no it was package for project you have to install Redis server in your system https://redis.io/download

Comment: @DanielMesa redis-cli after run this commend showing "command not found".

Comment: Default cach driver file is working properly. Can i used this into my project ?

Comment: You can use Cache driver but you must install and run redis-server